# Host Actions On Google App With Dialogflow Using Node JS on Self Hosted HTTPS Server (MalformedResponse: Webhook error (206))

Tags: node.js, https, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have created one app in actions on google with dialogflow using nodejs. First it is hosted on heroku server, but now i want to host in my server with https.

it works properly on heroku server but not working on my server. It returns error "MalformedResponse: Webhook error (206)"

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
const {
  dialogflow,
} = require('actions-on-google');

const app = dialogflow();
const expressApp = express().use(bodyParser.json());

// degault welcome intent on startup
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', conv => {  
    conv.ask('Hi, Ask me about Customer Ledger, Outstanding....');
});

app.intent('Default Fallback Intent', conv => {
  conv.ask('I didnt understand. Can you tell me something else?');
});


var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('ssl/office.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('ssl/office.crt')
};

var server = https.createServer(options, expressApp).listen(3000, function(){
    //express().use(bodyParser.json(), app);
    expressApp.post('/fulfillment', app);
  console.log("Express server listening on port 3000" );
});
```

Can anyone suggest me what is the problem with my code?[Simulator Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYJM4.png)

Comment: A 206 means the webhook responded successfully with an empty response. Is the response not being returned or in the wrong format?

Comment: i have compare response of heroku server & my node server 
i am not getting **delegatedResponse** array in response and in heroku server response i am getting it like below format

`delegatedResponse:{\"payload\":{\"google\":{\"expectUserResponse\":true,\"richResponse\":{\"items\":[{\"simpleResponse\":{\"textToSpeech\":\"Hi, what can i do for you....\"}}]}}}}`

Comment: I don't think 'delegatedResponse' is expected. I think you're just supposed to go with 'payload'

Answer (score 0):

If you are using express and there is no other layer in between (like Heroku has) to forward requests from port 443 to 3000, the request might not be reaching the target port

Comment: sorry, I am new to node js. can you please explain it in deep?

Comment: So when you are hosting it outside of Heroku, what does the endpoint look like?

Comment: https://myurl.com:3000/fulfillment

**my domain url in place of myurl.com**

Comment: Is this over HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: fulfillment url without https is not allowed in dialogflow

Comment: Can you verify if the endpoint is working over HTTPS? It could work over HTTP since you are specifying the port but not over HTTPS since it defaults to port 443 and not 3000

Comment: So your request is not reaching the desired port. Have a read at this [article](https://contextneutral.com/story/creating-an-https-server-with-nodejs-and-express) and run the express server on 443 instead of 3000 and try it

Comment: Resulting endpoint should be https://myurl.com/fulfillment without "3000"